# Fitting a distribution to match known points on the CDF

Tags: r, optimization

I've recently run into a situation where I know a few probability points in the tail of a distribution and I want to "fit" a distribution that goes through these points in the tail. I realize this is messy and not overly accurate, and plagued with conceptual issues. However, trust me that I really want to do this.

So effectively I know some points in the tail of the CDF with `x` being the values and `y` being the probability of that value or smaller. Here's R code to illustrate my data:

```
x <- c(0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85)
y <- c(0.0666666666666667, 0.0625, 0.0659340659340659, 0.0563106796116505, 
       0.0305676855895196, 0.0436953807740325, 0.0267459138187221)
```

Then I create a function to minimize error between my data and a beta distribution CDF using `pbeta`. I use SSE as a fit metric then minimize that with `-sum`. I throw in an initial guess as the first param to `optim` of `(9, .8)` although I've tried this with different guesses and I always get the same result. The starting point guess I use comes from manually cooking up parameters by hand that seem close.

```
# function to optomize with optim
beta_func <- function(par, x) -sum( (pbeta( x, par[1], par[2]) - y)**2 ) 
out <- optim(c(9,.8), beta_func, lower=c(1,.5), upper=c(200,200), method="L-BFGS-B", x=x)

out <- out$par
print(out)
#> [1]  0.90000 23.40294
```

Below I graph the 'optimized' beta distribution in red, my actual data in blue, and a hand tweaked starting guess of the beta parameters in black.

```
plot(function(x) pbeta(x, shape1=out[1], shape2=out[2] ), 0, 1.5, col='red')
plot(function(x) pbeta(x, 9,.8), 0, 1.5, col='black', add=TRUE)
lines(x,y, col='blue')
```

[image]

I can't grok what's going on with `optim` to give a solution that's worse than my starting guess. I calculated the SSE for my starting guess vs the `optim` solution and it looks like my guess has a much larger -SSE:

```
# my guess
-sum( (pbeta( x, 9, .8) - y)**2)
#> [1] -0.03493344

# optim's output
-sum( (pbeta( x, .9, 23) - y)**2)
#> [1] -6.314587
```

Using past history as my Bayesian prior, my guess is that I'm misunderstanding `optim` or feeding it improper inputs. However, I can't grok what's going on. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried using the `CG` optimization method, but the results are not meaningfully different and still don't seem near as good as my starting guess.

```
out <- optim(c(9,.8), beta_func, method="CG", x=x)
out <- out$par
print(out)
#> [1]  2.287611 11.124736
```

Comment: How can these points be "known" for a CDF and yet tend to decrease with increasing values of $x$ ?

Comment: I think these are problems which would disappear if you were to estimate these quantities using standard statistical tools instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @JimB the source of the downward slope is two fold. Estimates of each point come from a different sampling process so two things happen: 1) sample noise 2) violation of the iid assumption about each underlying. I'm not concerned as much with the stats issues here as much as trying to make `optim` do my bidding.

Comment: @Sycorax your suggestion presumes that standard statistical tools would work in my situation. That's an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are accidentally trying to maximize the squared errors.  The default for optim() is to minimize the function, so the negative sign in your beta_func() results in searching for a max.

If you modify your function like so you get values closer to your guess:

```
beta_func2 <- function(par, x) sum( (pbeta( x, par[1], par[2]) - y)**2 ) 
out2 <- optim(c(9,.8), beta_func2, lower=c(1,.5), upper=c(200,200), method="L-BFGS-B", x=x)
out2 <- out2$par
print(out2)
[1] 11.04296  0.50000
```

You can check the new function against your observations (where out, x, and y are defined as in your example):

```
plot(x,(pbeta(x,out[1],out[2])), ylim=c(-.1,1), col="red", type="l")
points(x, (pbeta(x,9,0.8)), col="black", type="l")
points(x,(pbeta(x,out2[1],out2[2])), col="orange", type="l")
lines(x,y, col='blue')
title(main="Blue observed CDF, black guesstimate, gold optimized")
```

[image]

Comment: yep, that was clearly my mistake. I *thought* I had tried changing the sign, on a whim, but clearly I had not. I was pretty anchored to the idea the the default behavior of `optim` was to maximize. Thanks!